# How to import color from colors.jsx to another file

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a src/config/colors.jsx file with the following code:

```
const colors = {
    pink: '#f1316b',
}

export default colors;
```

And I have another Button.jsx file as follows

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Button = styled.button`
  width: 100px;
  height: 48px;
  border-radius: 24px;
  background-color: #f1316b;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
`;

export default Button;
```

How do I import the color pink from colors to use as a background-color in buttons?

Comment: You have done everything correctly, now just import it like you usually import stuff. `import colors from "path"`

Comment: How can I call pink in background color correctly?

Comment: What if I add more colors to colors.jsx file how will I call the particular color I need?

Comment: colors is an object. Not jsx. You need to call colors.key for any color u want

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, this should be what your searching for. 
Import the `colors` constant and then use it as follows in the `Button`

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import colors from './config/colors.jsx' //or where your file is located

const Button = styled.button`
  width: 100px;
  height: 48px;
  border-radius: 24px;
  background-color: ${colors.pink};
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
`;

export default Button;
```

Comment: It's a default export. The destructure syntax won't work i think.

Comment: Also colors is an object. I think you mean colors.pink

Comment: Yes, your right. I didn't recognize it directly. I changed the code.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure of your folder structure but inside Button component (assuming its also in `src` folder), just do

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import colors from './config/colors.jsx';

const Button = styled.button`
  width: 100px;
  height: 48px;
  border-radius: 24px;
  background-color: colors.pink;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
`;

export default Button;
```

you can also add other colors that you want too

Answer (score 0):

first you don't need use your colors file as `jsx`, rename it to `colors.js` and import it to your component:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import colors from './config/colors'

const Button = styled.button`
  width: 100px;
  height: 48px;
  border-radius: 24px;
  background-color:colors.pink;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
`;

export default Button;
```